Flutter> Patrol > Mobile automatization test: Running a set of tests from one folder
How can you run a set of tests from a folder so that an issue with one test doesn't prevent the execution of the remaining tests?
The following hierarchy of the integration_test directory:
integration_test
├── patrol
   ├── 1_test.dart
   ├── 2_test.dart ( broken) 
   ├── 3_test.dart

Command to run tests (windows):
patrol test -t integration_test\patrol\

Execution of test on the device:
--------In the loop:
first test run  1_test.dart passed

second test run  2_test.dart failed ( The test froze during the test execution, it looks like patrol waits forever for a condition/element to be met, but it should take 5 seconds? ) 

third test  run 3_test.dart not started 

How can you run a set of tests from a folder so that an issue with one test doesn't prevent the execution of the remaining tests? Is there a command or a project setting to run all tests regardless of the result and generate a report from the test results?
Note: The test stalls in the case the condition is not met, such as in the case of: expect(tester('Classifications').visible, equals(true));
or if it cannot find the element it is searching for, like:
await tester('Classifications').tap();

Instead, the test should fail and then proceed to the next file.
I temporarily added a timeout for the entire test, but this is not an elegant solution to the problem...

One option is to use the tags, you can define tags on the test and then you can specify what all tests should be running.
You can define tags with patrolTest as below, for e.g. below test is tagged as smoke-tests
patrolTest(test scenario 1', tags: 'smoke-tests', ($) async {

now below command will run all the tests marked with tag smoke-tests in all the tests under integration_test folder
`patrol test  --tags smoke-tests`

The tags filter can be used with the target file as well
patrol test -t integration_test/patrol/1_test.dart --tags=smoke-tests
Your other option is to use --exclude-tags and patrol will exclude all the tags defined.
For e.g. below command will run all tests in 1_test.dart and exclude all tests marked with flaky
patrol test -t integration_test/patrol/1_test.dart --exclude-tags=flaky 
and below will run all tests in integration_test folder excluding all tests tagged as flaky
patrol test --exclude-tags=flaky 
